# Could not load assembly 'Microsoft.VisualBasic.Activities.Compiler, ...Perhaps it doesn't exist in the Mono for Android profile?

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

Exception while loading assemblies: `System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load assembly 'Microsoft.VisualBasic.Activities.Compiler, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'`. Perhaps it doesn't exist in the Mono for Android profile?

This is my first time trying `Xamarin`, I have created a `web api`, my goal is to feed the data on button click from android. I'm using `async` and `await` to call `HttpWebRequest`. I don't know why all of a sudden it started complaining. Any suggestion why I'm having this error?